# Upload JPEG to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, jpg

I want to add an "World Image" Datastore to my GeoServer, based on a georeferenced JPEG that I have on my local drive. Can I upload it to the GeoServer data folder from within the GeoServer application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to move the image files to the server data directory.  You may create another folder named "aerials" in it and paste the image files to it.  Finally, when creating the WorldImage store use the URL option to browse to the image:

[image]

note:

> A world file is a plain text file used to georeference raster map
>   images. This file (often with an extension of .jgw or .tfw)
>   accompanies an associated image file (.jpg or .tif). Together, the
>   world file and the corresponding image file is known as a WorldImage
>   in GeoServer.